Remove unicode character in snowflake sql
I have country column with values in it.
There is a value with extra space and with TRIM(UPPER(country)) is not returning the value.
Country
India 
Sweden
USA

If India as space at the end and it is not actually a space, then how to remove it. (No need to remove any foreign characters and special characters).

plenty of duplicates.Remove non-ASCII characters from a string in Snowflake or Remove all Unicode space separators in PostgreSQL?

or How to trim string (with Ideographic space U+3000) in sql server? or Whitespace in a database field is not removed by trim()

try with regex:
SELECT 
    TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(country), '^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$', '')) AS cleaned_country
FROM 
    your_table;

